# Add IoC in Program.cs file in .NET 8 from Dependency Container

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, dependencies, .net-8.0

This is my IoC method in Dependency Container

```
public class DependencyContainer
{
    public static void RegisterServices(IServiceCollection service)
    {
        #region Services Injection

        service.AddScoped<IUserService, UserService>();

        #endregion

        #region Repositories Injection

        service.AddScoped<IUserRepository, UserRepository>();

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Now I want to add it in Program .cs in web Layer .
How can I do it in .NET 8?

in .NET 5 it was:

```
    public static void RegisterServices(IServiceCollection services)
 {
  DependencyContainer.RegisterServices(services);
  }
```

but in .NET 8 that we have not public method, how can I do it?

[image]

Comment: What is the second `RegisterServices` which calls `DependencyContainer.RegisterServices`? Can you share the contents of the `Program.cs`?

Comment: @GuruStron I share it , I dont know how can I call it in program.cs in dot.net 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`WebApplicationBuilder` returned by the `WebApplication.CreateBuilder` exposes [`Services`](https://WebApplicationBuilder.Services) property of type `IServiceCollection` which is used exactly for the purpose of DI services registrations, so:

```
DependencyContainer.RegisterServices(builder.Services);
```

This is covered in the migration to 6.0 docs:

- [New hosting model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/50-to-60?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio#new-hosting-model)
- [Code samples migrated to the new minimal hosting model in ASP.NET Core 6.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/50-to-60-samples?view=aspnetcore-8.0)

Comment: I had to write in at the  end of program.cs file? or should write buttom of? builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
  
    var app = builder.Build();

Comment: @masoudmazloum you should write it before `var app = builder.Build();`. More precise location is up to you.

Comment: Before that code: builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews(); ? right?

Comment: @masoudmazloum usually it should not matter.